# struts 2 iterator print the next value

Tags: jquery, struts2

I got a List of type string with values say for example
 List str = {"start", "hi", "hello", "start", "hello", "hi"}
If value is start i want to print the next iterator value.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the current value's index from the status object:

```
<s:iterator value="str" status="stat">
    <p>After <s:property/> comes <s:property value="str[#stat.index+1]"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Nice one! I tried using the `var` attribute of the iterator tag, until I found your tip with the `value` attribute. Works like a charm.